# String/Character Font Mapping using recursion in C#

Tags: c#, fonts, mapping

I am creating a Font Mapping program where I want to map 2 fonts of different languages.

For eg `A` in Arial Font(English) will map with `अ` in Kruti Dev Font(Hindi).

I have a created this conversion in a database this way:

```
Native_Font     |     Foreign_Language_Font
-------------------------------------------
       A        |              अ
       B        |              बी
```

If conversion was restricted only for characters it was OK. Read each character of native font and find its matching character in Foreign Language Font. (I have done it)

But now I have to do it for strings also and that's where the real problem starts.

If a string is provided in database, then convert it fully. But if its conversion does not exist find conversion for one character less.

An example would be

In Database

```
Native_Font     |     Foreign_Language_Font
-------------------------------------------
    Cha         |              चा
     r          |              र
     t          |              ट
```

and word `Chart` is given to translate.

1. It would first try to convert Full word `Chart`. If its mapping is found give at once.
2. But if it does not find direct conversion for `Chart` then Go for `Char`. If its mapping is found give at once, then find respective character of `t`

and so on

```
Chart

Char t

Cha rt
Cha r t

Ch art
Ch ar t
Ch a r t

C hart
C har t
C ha r t
C h a r t
```

Moreover if a mapping is not found, it should be replaced by native font character. How to do it? I am sure recursion should be used. But How?

Comment: I am little bit concerned about this approach of yours, let suppose there is a word "watched", now your logic will find watched in database, its not found, than watche which is not found, now it will look for watch, which is found, but this watch is not same as of watched, I hope I have conveyed my concern.

Comment: I hope you are sure you are not going to run into conflicts with this mapping stuff. For eg. suppose you have the following items in your mapping: CHA, CH, AR, T. Seemingly this is enough to translate the word Chart. Now applying your logic we might end up picking CHA first then we would be left with no option for R. Instead we could have picked CH, AR & T. I am worried that if your database extends to say hundreds of combinations from the 26 letters you might end up having these conflicts...I am sure you must be taking care of this....

Comment: @ImranBalouch I think its not like if he gets a match for "watch" he is satisfied. He would then go look for "ed" if not found then he will go look for "e" & "d" separately which are sure to have an entry. Then he would concat his result. @ Nikhil plz correct me if I am wrong, if not then what I mentioned in my earlier comment is a legitimate issue...

Comment: @ArifEqbal: Exactly like you explained to Imran.

Comment: What is your final goal? Transliteration from English to Hindi? There might be other ways in that case.

Comment: @ananthonline: Transliteration Exactly. What other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd approach it with a greedy algorithm.  Something like this:

```
    // warning, untested
    public String Translate(String s, Dictionary<String, String> mapping)
    {
        String result = "";
        if (RecurTranslate(s, mapping, ref result))
            return result;

        throw new Exception("No translation");
    }

    private bool RecurTranslate(String s, Dictionary<String, String> mapping, ref String result)
    {
        if (s.Length == 0)
            return true;

        for (int prefixLen = s.Length; prefixLen > 0; --prefixLen)
        {
            String prefix = s.Substring(0, prefixLen);
            String trans;
            if (mapping.TryGetValue(prefix, out trans))
            {
                if (RecurTranslate(s.Substring(prefixLen), mapping, ref result))
                {
                    result = trans + result;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else if (prefixLen == 1)
            {   // this branch allows a character to stand for itself
                if (RecurTranslate(s.Substring(prefixLen), mapping, ref result))
                {
                    result = prefix + result;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

This starts from the front, looking for the largest possible match.  Depending on your data, other approaches might be better - say, going through the mapping in length order to find the longest match and splitting from there:

```
    private bool RecurTranslate2(String s, Dictionary<String, String> mapping, ref String result)
    {
        if (s.Length == 0)
            return true;

        foreach (var entry in mapping.Where(e => e.Key.Length <= s.Length).OrderByDescending(e => e.Key.Length))
        {
            if (s.Contains(entry.Key))
            {   // split into a before and after
                int idx = s.IndexOf(entry.Key);
                String before = s.Substring(0, idx);
                String after = s.Substring(idx + entry.Key.Length);
                String bRes = "", aRes = "";
                if (RecurTranslate2(before, mapping, ref bRes) && RecurTranslate2(after, mapping, ref aRes))
                {
                    result = aRes + entry.Value + bRes;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Finally, you might play with combining these methods: use RecurTranslate2 until you get to some length threshold and then switch to RecurTranslate.

Responding to comment: See new else branch for failed lookup

Comment: +1 from OP (that's me). Your first method `RecurTranslate` works. I have a query that if a mapping is not found, i want to put original character there. What changes should i do in `RecurTranslate` to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Recursive version - O(2^(string.Length-1)) - dont run on larger strings

```
[Test]
    public void StringSplit()
    {

        var splits = AllPossibleSplits("hello".Select(c => c.ToString()).ToList());

        Assert.AreEqual(16, splits.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual("hello", splits.First().First());
        Assert.AreEqual("hello".Length, splits.Last().Count());
    }

    private List<List<string>> AllPossibleSplits(List<string> source)
    {

        if (source.Count == 0)
        {
            return new List<List<string>>();
        }
        if (source.Count == 1)
        {
            return new List<List<string>> { source };
        }
        var firstTwoJoined = new List<string> { source[0] + source[1] };
        firstTwoJoined.AddRange(source.Skip(2));

        var justFirst = new List<string> { source[0] };
        var withoutFirst = AllPossibleSplits(source.Skip(1).ToList());

        var result = new List<List<string>>();
        result.AddRange(AllPossibleSplits(firstTwoJoined));
        result.AddRange(withoutFirst.Select(list => justFirst.Concat(list).ToList()));

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: This way the results are sorted by number of splits (source string without any splits will be first)

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this problem differently, perhaps using [phonemes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneme). What you want is a process that converts

English text -> English phonemes -> Hindi representations of each phoneme (or combinations) -> Hindi transliterated string.

One open-source string to phoneme synthesizer is [eSpeak](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/index.html). Using [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/espeak/forums/forum/538920/topic/2343895) method, you can get only the phonemes from the library (discard the wave buffers). Now scan the english phonemes and pick Hindi fragments from a map.

*Note: You can choose any library that converts a given string in English to the standard phoneme map, eSpeak is just one that I have seen before*

This method should yield better results and seems to me to be a "natural" solution to this problem.

Hope this helps!